# how to render context to my template, what am i missing

Tags: python, django

this seems really basic but I don't know why it's working. I should probably mention I'm using django haystack first, and I'm trying to send some context(in my views.py) to the template that has good features of django haystack.

So in my views.py

```
def search(request):
    hotCat = Category.objects.get_hotCat()
    context = {
        'hotCat':hotCat
    }
    return render(request, 'search/search.html',context)
```

And in my search/search.html I did 
{{hotCat}}
but nothing shows up.

Here;s my full code for search.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<style>
#div_id_models{
    visibility: hidden;
}

</style>



{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-3">

    <form method="get" action=".">
        <table>
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search-button"  style="margin-top:-130px;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        {% if query %}

            {% for result in page.object_list %}
                <p>
                    <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.name }}</a>
                </p>
            {% empty %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
                <div>
                    {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="/category/{{post.category}}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                    |
                    {% if page.has_next %}<a href="/category/{{post.category}}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
        {% endif %}
    </form>
</div>

{{hotCat}}
{%endblock%}
```

Is this because I'm using haystack? for other template, this worked fine...

Edit I have search_indexes.py that looks like

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from main.models import Category


class ArticleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Category

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

I tried adding search function but no difference

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^activity/', include('actstream.urls')),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^main/search/',include('haystack.urls')),


    url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/edit/$',views.profile_edit,
       name='userena_profile_edit'),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),



]
```

Comment: did you check if the value is coming from the backend? Tried printing in views before sending it to the template?

Comment: What is `get_hotCat()`?

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja yeah it gets printed but not being sent to template

Comment: @user3100115 that's from my model. even with simple thing like hello:"hello" does not get rendered through to template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't passed the `query` object to your template. The haystack examples inherit from `SearchView` class view, you've used function based views . I am guessing that's the problem.

EDIT:
The real reason for this issue is that you're `urls.py` points `/main/search` to haystack and thus the `search` function in the view isn't called.
The solution would be to use something like `SearchView` and add the `hotCat` value into the context_dict. Then point the `/main/search` to this view.

Eg:

```
class OwnSearchView(SearchView):

    template='search/search.html',
    form_class=SearchForm

  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
      context = super(OwnSearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
      # do something
      context['hotCat'] = 'hotCat' #get this however you like
      return context
```

And then in your `urls.py`

```
url(r'^main/search/', OwnSearchView.as_view(),  name='haystack_search'),
```

)

You will need to add the variable values according to your code. Haystack docs have further details regarding the `form_class` and `queryset`.

Comment: hello, yes I have that class view which I edited in the question, but still can't render.....what am I doing wrong..

Comment: Do you not see hotCat after a post? Or in general too? I am guessing your get requests would work fine (since they run using the `search` function) and the posts won't as they come through haystack. Am I right?

Comment: in general I can see hotCat, it's only occuring in search.html. search functionality works but post won't come through. hmm I think search.html isn't getting run by search function since even "hello":hello won't come through...which Is why I'm so lost ...

Comment: Can you confirm once whether loading `search.html` actually runs the `search` function? My guess is that file is being rendered using haystack views and your code isn't being run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105975/discussion-between-sudhanshu-shekhar-and-mike-braa).

Comment: hey man can you check out this one;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967551/category-matching-query-does-not-exist-i-dont-understand-why-its-sending-me-t